# Monit cannot start/stop service

Tags: monit

Monit cannot start/stop service,
If i stop the service, just stop monitoring the service in Monit.
Attached the log and config for reference.

```
    #Monitor vsftpd#
check process vsftpd
 matching vsftpd
 start program = "/usr/sbin/vsftpd start"
 stop program = "/usr/sbin/vsftpd stop"
if failed port 21 protocol ftp then restart
```

Comment: Jul 19 10:42:34 mc-cacti monit[47088]: 'vsftpd' stop on user request
Jul 19 10:42:34 mc-cacti monit[47088]: Monit daemon with PID 47088 awakened
Jul 19 10:42:34 mc-cacti monit[47088]: Awakened by User defined signal 1
Jul 19 10:42:34 mc-cacti monit[47088]: 'vsftpd' stop: '/usr/sbin/vsftpd stop'

Answer (score 0):

The log states: "**stop on user request**". The process is stopped and monitoring is disabled, since monitoring a stopped (= non existing) process makes no sense.

If you *Restart service* (by cli or web) it should print `info: 'test' restart on user request` to the log and call the stop program and continue with the start program (if no dedicated *restart* program is provided).

In fact one problem can arise: if the stop scripts fails to create the expected state (=`NOT(check process matching vsftpd)`), the start program is not called. So if there is a task running that matches `vsftpd`, monit will not call the start program. So it's always better to use a PID file for monitoring where possible.

Finally - and since not knowing what system/versions you are on, an assumption: The `vsftpd` binary on my system is really only the daemon. It is not supporting any options. All arguments are configuration files as stated in [the man page](https://linux.die.net/man/8/vsftpd). So supplying start and stop only tries to create new daemons loading `start` and `stop` file. -- If this is true, the *one problem* described above applies, since your `vsftpd` is never stopped.